# How to redefine \section to include "long-title" in the ToC?

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, sectioning, titlesec

**OBS: I've made a previous post about my problem, but I was not clear enough. Therefore I will try again!**

I'm working on a math lecture notes template, and have the following:

```
\section[Lecture \thesection: <<title>>]{Lecture \thesection}
```

where `\thesection` is the lecture number (i.e. section number) and "title" is the section title. Some courses have well over thirty lectures, so it does get very repetitive; not to mention bad programming. I want something like this:

```
\section{<<title>>}
```

[image]

but want it to *behave* like the former. I have tried to use `\renewcommand`, changing in the `\titleformat` and the  `\let\old` redefinition, but nothing have worked so far. Here is my MWE with all section and table of contents commands.

#### MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

% ----- Packages --------------------------------------------

\usepackage{titlesec} % Section formatting
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft} % ToC formatting
\usepackage[toc]{multitoc} % ToC formatting


% ----- Section formatting ----------------------------------

\titleformat{\section}
    {\sffamily\Large\bfseries}
    {\!{\fontsize{24}{24}\selectfont\textreferencemark}\;\;}
    {0em}
    {} % Tried: "Lecture \thesection" here. Didn't work!


% ----- ToC formatting --------------------------------------

\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{3pt}
\cftsetindents{section}{0em}{0em}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\sffamily\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecpagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{}

\renewcommand*{\multicolumntoc}{2}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}

\makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\cftsecpresnum}{\begin{lrbox}{\@tempboxa}}
    \renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{\end{lrbox}}
\makeatother
-------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents % ToC

% Beginning of contents
% \section[long-title]{short-title}
\section[Lecture \thesection: First topic]{Lecture \thesection}
Lorem ipsum...

\section[Lecture \thesection: Second topic]{Lecture \thesection}
Lorem ipsum...

\section[Lecture \thesection: Third topic]{Lecture \thesection}
Lorem ipsum...

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: the markup looks very odd how come you are needing to use `\thesection` in the title of a numbered section???

Comment: oh you are throwing away the section number with lrbox then adding it back by hand, that's basically the cause of the problem

Comment: Your code does not compile (without error) because of the `--`… line and option `subfigure`. Please note, that a minimal *working* example should not result in errors not related to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `\section` explicitly, define a suitable command, here `\lecture`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}

% ----- Packages --------------------------------------------

\usepackage{titlesec} % Section formatting
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft} % ToC formatting
\usepackage[toc]{multitoc} % ToC formatting


% ----- Section formatting ----------------------------------

\titleformat{\section}
    {\sffamily\Large\bfseries}
    {{\fontsize{24.88}{0}\selectfont\textreferencemark}\enspace}
    {0em}
    {Lecture \thesection}


% ----- ToC formatting --------------------------------------

\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{3pt}
\cftsetindents{section}{0em}{0em}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\sffamily\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecpagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{}

\renewcommand*{\multicolumntoc}{2}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}

\makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\cftsecpresnum}{\begin{lrbox}{\@tempboxa}}
    \renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{\end{lrbox}}
\makeatother
%-------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\lecture}[1]{%
  \section[Lecture \thesection: #1]{}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents % ToC

\lecture{First topic}
Lorem ipsum...

\lecture{Second topic}
Lorem ipsum...

\lecture{Third topic}
Lorem ipsum...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all: It is seldom a good idea to use more than one package to configure the table of contents, list of figures etc. Independent from this, package `multitoc` can result in empty lists of floats, e.g., if you add a `\listoffigures` without adding option `lof`. It also does not support additional list of floats like the one of package `listings` or generating using packages like `newfloat`, `float` or `tocbasic`. These also will be empty.

In my opinion wishes likes yours are easier to realize when using a class that already supports many of the wanted features. So here an example using `scrartcl` instead of `article`:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{multicol}

% Changinging the output if the section number in \section:
\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{%
  {\fontsize{24}{24}\selectfont\textreferencemark}\enskip
  Lecture \thesection
}

% Changing the section ToC entries:
\setkomafont{sectionentry}{\normalfont}% Don't use sans-serif bold for the
                                       % section ToC entries.
\newcommand*{\LectureTOCNumFormat}[1]{\let\autodot:Lecture #1}% New definition.
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[%
  dynnumwidth,% automatic adapt the width reserved for the number
  entrynumberformat=\LectureTOCNumFormat,% use the new definition above for
                                % the number
  beforeskip=0pt,% no vertical space above section entires
]{section}{section}

% Two columns for the ToC:
\BeforeStartingTOC[toc]{\begin{multicols}{2}}% 
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\end{multicols}}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}

% Redefinition of \section to use the mandatory argument for the ToC (and page
% head with page style headings) only.
\NewCommandCopy{\Section}{\section}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{som}{%
  \IfValueT{#2}{%
    \GenericWarning{}{Optional \string\section\space argument ignored}%
  }%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \Section*{#3}%
  }{%
    \Section[{#3}]{}%
  }%
}

%-------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents % ToC

% Beginning of contents
% \section[long-title]{short-title}
\section{First topic}
Lorem ipsum...

\section{Second topic}
Lorem ipsum...

\section{Third topic}
Lorem ipsum...

\end{document}
```

Note: Because of `dynnumwidth` you need at least three LaTeX runs to get:

[image]

Alternatively you can use an explicit width, e.g., `numwidth=4.75em`.

As you can see, only one additional package is needed: `multicol`.

Answer (score 1):

It is really silly to just eat the section number and then print it yourself by making it part of the title. Why not just use `tocloft` and `titlesec` to format things the way you want? (Incidentally, I am always nervous combining more than one `toc`-formatting packages together; `tocloft` contains code specifically to work around some things that `titlesec` does.)

Quick explanation of the code below. List number corresponds to the lines marked in the comments in the code below.

1. By using `[explicit]` for `titlesec` you need to explicitly include `#1` in the `\titleformat` to print the title text. And by *not* including it, you suppress the section title from being printed at all.
2. Instead wrapping the the section number by `lrbox` to eat it, why not just print `Lecture`  before it and `:` after it, as you are meant to with those commands?
3. Of course, if you do so, you should reserve enough space for `Lecture XX:` to print properly. I estimated it at `5em`, but you can change it to fit.
4. And voila, you get to just call `\section{<title>}` as you wished for in your question.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}

% ----- Packages --------------------------------------------

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec} % Item 1
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft} 
\usepackage[toc]{multitoc} 


% ----- Section formatting ----------------------------------

\titleformat{\section}
    {\sffamily\Large\bfseries}
    {{\fontsize{24.88}{0}\selectfont\textreferencemark}\enspace}
    {0em}
    {Lecture \thesection}  % Item 1


% ----- ToC formatting --------------------------------------

\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{3pt}
\cftsetindents{section}{0em}{5em}    % Item 3
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\sffamily\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecpagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{}

\renewcommand*{\multicolumntoc}{2}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}

\renewcommand{\cftsecpresnum}{Lecture }   % Item 2
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{:}        % Item 2
%-------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents 

\section{First topic}    % Item 4   
Lorem ipsum...

\section{Second topic}
Lorem ipsum...

\section{Third topic}
Lorem ipsum...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked like a sharm.